# How to remove startup program/service which starts during booting?

Tags: boot, startup

I installed EC2 Cloud tools. Which made me wait for 60 sec during boot-up.

Later I removed the tool but unfortunately the program was still there and waits for 60 sec during startup.

How to I see what program/service starts during bootup and how do I remove it.

Comment: Although bum is the correct answer but sudo apt-get --purge remove package solved the problem I was facing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the man page for `apt-get` use

`sudo apt-get --purge remove package`

to also delete the configuration files associated with that package.

You can also take a look in **System->Preferences->Startup Applications**.

On the other hand, you can always know what processes are currently running on your machine using **System->Administration->System Monitor**, clicking on the **Processes** tab. If you find a process which name is related to EC2, then you can `locate` the binary (remember to `sudo updatedb` before using it). To find out which package installed it, first enter

`sudo apt-get install dlocate`

and afterwards

`dlocate /path/to/binary`.

Finally, remove the package using `apt-get`.

Answer (score 7):

Install `boot up manager` and have a look at the list of startup applications you can turn on and off. Random example of the lay-out of `bum`:

[image]